# What is the mathematical structure behind the statistical physics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, mathematics, phase-space

It is well known (relatively) that the classical mechanics (especially the analytical mechanics) can be formulated as vector fields on the tangent bundle (Lagrangian formulation) or cotangent bundle or a more general symplectic manifold (Hamiltonian formulation).

And for quantum mechanics (classical ones), we have it formulated on the $L^2$ space of wave functions.

And for electrodynamics and relativity, we have a Pseudo-Riemann metric on the linear spacetime or spacetime manifold.

Then what about thermodynamics and statistical mechanics?

It is argued by Arnold that there is a contact structure for thermodynamic variables. But I am not sure to what extend this contact structure can formulate thermodynamics. Besides, it seems that this contact structure is entirely unrelated to the statistical description of thermodynamic systems. And also, the probability structure in the statistical mechanics is seldom mentioned by mathematics.

So the question is, **What is the mathematical structure behind the statistical physics** Why don't we see some mathematics to statistical physics, like symplectic geometry to Hamiltonian mechanics? Is it too hard or too simple or just unimportant?

Comment: *Why don't we see some mathematics to statistical physics?* Does the renormalization group count? Or combinatorics? How did $E_8$ pop out of a model of magnetism? It seems like there’s plenty of math in statistical physics.

Comment: @Ghoster Yes you are right. There are indeed plenty of mathematics problems related to statistical physics. However, what you mentioned are for very specific questions. What I wonder is that whether there is a *whole mathematical structure* that can somehow contain the entire subject, like symplectic manifolds for Hamiltonian mechanics.

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: Maybe Khinchin’s *Mathematical Foundations of Statistical Mechanics* would be worth reading, since he was a mathematician and would perhaps be most interested in unifying structures. (I haven’t read it.)

Comment: Look for [Geometrothermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrothermodynamics)

Comment: Arguably you could say statistical mechanics is about deriving and understanding the consequences of [maximum entropy probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) for different classes of probability distributions.

Comment: @Andrew can we say that statistical mechanics is an application of classical probability theory to fundamental physics theories?

Comment: I would agree with @RyderRude that, in its most general form, (equilibrium classical) statistical mechanics is just part of probability theory. If you wish, it is the analysis of properties of *Gibbs measures*. There are whole books on this topic (for instance [this one](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250329/html)). Of course, you can consider specific subfields of (equilibrium classical) mechanics, such as its application to Hamiltonian systems. Then, one has additional structure, but this goes beyond the fundamental theory.

Comment: For *quantum* (equilibrium) statistical mechanics, you should probably replace probability theory with $C^*$-algebras. A classical reference in this setting is [this one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02520-8). Beyond equilibrium, I would say that there is no general theory of statistical mechanics at the moment, even at the physics level of rigour.

Comment: @RyderRude Basically yes, but specifically looking at maximum entropy distributions for different classes of probability distributions, where the class of distribution (discrete vs continuous, what parameters are varied, what constraints are placed, etc) is motivated by physics.